# Where is Linux root filesystem on an attached drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, centos, lvm

I have a CentOS system with many configurations/applications installed on a hard drive. I have installed a new CentOS system on a different hard drive. I have booted from the new system/hard drive and I have the old system/hard drive installed in the same box. I wish to access the root filesystem of the old system/hard drive. I am not sure where the filesystem is located. I have tried to mount the Linux LVM partition of the old drive but I am nor really sure how to do it. Is there an easy way to do this?

---

Here is the output of mount:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=12248244k,nr_inodes=3062061,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
10.0.0.5:/backups on /mnt/nfs/backups type nfs (rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.5,mountvers=3,mountport=59250,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=all,addr=10.0.0.5)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/0/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Here is the output of lsblk:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2            8:2    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 929.6G  0 part 
  ├─centos-swap 253:0    0  11.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─centos-root 253:1    0    49G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 868.7G  0 lvm  /home
```

Here is the output of lsblk when booted from new system/drive: (I wish to access the old system.)

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   931G  0 part 
  ├─centos-swap 253:0    0  11.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─centos-root 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 869.2G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0   500M  0 part 
├─sdb2            8:18   0   500M  0 part 
└─sdb3            8:19   0 929.6G  0 part
```

Here is the output of pvs when booted from new system/drive:

```
PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  931.02g    0 
/dev/sdb3  centos lvm2 a--  929.55g    0
```

I wish to mount the centos VG located on /dev/sdb3.

Comment: It would be far easier to figure out if you booted to that old drive and ran `mount`, `lsblk` and examined the output.   If you can post that output here and we might be able to help.

Comment: I added the output of mount and lsblk to the question. Not really sure how to use it.

Comment: From your mount you see `/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)` so you know that `/dev/mapper/centos-root` is your root device.  From lsblk you see that `entos-root` is part of an lvm volume stored on sda3.

Comment: How can I mount the LVM located on sda3? (when booted from the new system)
Both the LVMs are named centos so I am not sure how to specify it.

Comment: Correction: Both Volume Groups are named centos

Comment: That is going to be a problem.  I am not sure how to fix that.  You may be able to rename one when it is offline.  You'll need to research that.

Comment: Thanks for your help Zoredache. I figured it out. (See answer above.)

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.
Since both Volume Groups had the same name, the method I found [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/296) was not working.
I booted from the old system without the new drive attached and renamed the Volume Group using [vgrename](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgrename).
Then the above method worked.

So I did the following:

```
//boot into old system with old drive not attached
vgrename centos centos_old

//boot into new system with old drive attached
vgscan
vgchange -a y
mount /dev/centos_old/root /mnt/old_root
```